# ANOVA with block design and repeated measures

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm attempting to run some statistical analyses on a field trial that was constructed over 2 sites over the same growing season.

At both sites (`Site`, levels: HF|NW) the experimental design was a RCBD with 4 (n=4) blocks (`Block`, levels: 1|2|3|4 within each `Site`).
There were 4 treatments - 3 different forms of nitrogen fertiliser and a control (no nitrogen fertiliser) (`Treatment`, levels: AN, U, IU, C).
During the field trial there were 3 distinct periods that commenced with fertiliser addition and ended with harvesting of the grass. These periods have been given the levels 1|2|3 under the factor `N_app`.

There are a range of measurements that I would like to test the following null hypothesis H0 on:

`Treatment` (H0) had no effect on measurement

Two of the measurements I am particularly interested in are: grass yield and ammonia emissions.

Starting with grass yield (`Dry_tonnes_ha`) as
shown [here, a nice balanced data set](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ramntwdgpn0e3/HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv?dl=0)

The data can be downloaded in R using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

download.file('https://www.dropbox.com/s/w5ramntwdgpn0e3/HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv?raw=1', destfile = "HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv", method = "auto")
raw_data <- read.csv("HF_NW_grass_yield_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

HF_NW_grass <- raw_data %>% mutate_at(vars(Site, N_app, Block, Plot, Treatment), as.factor) %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
         Treatment = factor(Treatment, levels = c("AN", "U", "IU", "C")))
```

I have had a go at running an ANOVA on this using the following approach:

```
model_1 <- aov(formula = Dry_tonnes_ha ~ Treatment * N_app + Site/Block, data = HF_NW_grass, projections = TRUE)
```

I have a few concerns with this.

Firstly, what is the best way to test assumptions? For a simple one-way ANOVA I would use `shapiro.test()` and `bartlett.test()` on the dependent variable (`Dry_tonnes_ha`) to assess normality and heterogeneity of variance. Can I use the same approach here?

Secondly, I am concerned that `N_app` is a repeated measure as the same measurement is taken from the same plot over 3 different periods - what is the best way to build this repeated measures into the model?

Thirdly, I'm not sure of the best way to nest `Block` within `Site`. At both sites the levels of `Block` are 1:4. Do I need to have unique `Block` levels for each site?

I have [another data set for NH3 emissions here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ax16x95m2z3fb5/HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv?dl=0). R code to download:

```
download.file('https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ax16x95m2z3fb5/HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv?raw=1', destfile = "HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv", method = "auto")
raw_data_1 <- read.csv("HF_NW_NH3_emissions.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

HF_NW_NH3 <- raw_data_1 %>% mutate_at(vars(Site, N_app, Block, Plot, Treatment), as.factor) %>% 
  mutate(Treatment = factor(Treatment, levels = c("AN", "U", "IU", "C")))
```

For this I have all the concerns above with the addition that the data set is unbalanced.
At `HF` for `N_app` 1 n=3, but for `N_app` 2 & 3 n=4
At `NW` n=4 for all `N_app` levels.
At `NF` measurements were only made on the `Treatment` levels `U` and `IU`
At `NW` measuremnts were made on `Treatment` levels `AN`, `U` and `IU`

I'm not sure how to deal with this added level of complexity. I am tempted to just analyse as 2 separate site (the fact that the `N_app` periods are not the same at each site may encourage this approach).
Can I use a type iii sum of squares ANOVA here?

It has been suggested to me that a linear mixed modelling approach may be the way forward but I'm not familiar with using these.

I would welcome your thoughts on any of the above. Thanks for your time.

Rory

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question on the best way of testing assumptions. While your attempt of using another statistical test, implemented in R, is reasonable, I would actually just visualize the distribution and see if the data meet ANOVA assumptions. This approach may seem somewhat subjective, but it does work in most cases.

- independently, identically distributed (i.i.d) data: this is a question that you may already have an answer based on how much you know about your data. It's possible to use a chi-square test to determine independence (or not).
- normally distributed data: use a histogram / QQ plot to check. Based on the distribution, I think it is reasonable to use `aov` despite the slightly bimodal distribution.

(It appears that log-transformation help further meet normality assumption. This is something you may consider, especially for downstream analyses.)

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(density(HF_NW_grass$Dry_tonnes_ha), col="red", main="Density")
qqnorm(HF_NW_grass$Dry_tonnes_ha, col="red", main="qqplot")
qqline(HF_NW_grass$Dry_tonnes_ha)

DTH_trans <- log10(HF_NW_grass$Dry_tonnes_ha)
plot(density(DTH_trans), col="blue", main="transformed density")
qqnorm(DTH_trans, col="blue", main="transformed density")
qqline(DTH_trans)
```

Regarding your second question on what the best way to build repeated measures into the model is: Unfortunately, it is difficult to pinpoint such a "best" model, but based on my knowledge (mostly through genomics big data), you may want to use a linear mixed effect model. This can be implemented through the `lme4` R package, for example. Since it appears you already know how to construct a linear model in R, you should have no problem with applying `lme4` functions.

Your third question regarding whether to nest two variables is tricky. If I were you, I would start with `Site` and `Block` as if they were independent factors. However, if you  know they are not independent, you should probably nest them.

I think your questions and concerns are quite open-ended. My recommendation is that as long as you have a plausible justification, go ahead and proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your response.The more complex the stats gets the more subjective the process seems to be! Great info on the assumptions. I'm now questioning if I need a repeated measures. All of the measurements I am analysing occur only once for each `N_app`, the same `plot` is used for the 3 `N_app` periods which lead me to think a repeated measures was needed. Will have another look into linear mixed models. I may also simplify and analyse the two sites separately.

Comment: I guess the linear mixed models may also help with the unbalanced dataset. Though I guess I could use `Anova` here with type iii ss?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @David C on the use of visual diagnostics. Simple QQ plots should work

```
# dependent variable.
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
qqnorm(dt[,dry_tonnes_ha]); qqline(dt[,dry_tonnes_ha], probs= c(0.15, 0.85))
qqnorm(log(dt[,dry_tonnes_ha])); qqline(log(dt[,dry_tonnes_ha]), probs= c(0.15, 0.85))
```

[image]

The log transformation looks reasonable to me. You can also see this from the density plot, which is long tailed and somewhat bi-modal

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(density(dt[,dry_tonnes_ha]))
```

You could alternatively use lineup plots (Buja et al, 2009) if you wish. I'm not sure they're needed in this case. [Vignette provided](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nullabor/vignettes/nullabor.html)

```
library(nullabor)
# this may not be the best X variable. I'm not familiar with your data
dt_l <- lineup(null_permute("dry_tonnes_ha"), dt)
qplot(dry_tonnes_ha, treatment, data = dt_l) + facet_wrap(~ .sample)
```

[image]

For the other assumptions, you can just use the standard diagnostic plots from the `lm`

```
lm2 <- lm(log(dry_tonnes_ha) ~ treatment * n_app + site/block, data = dt)
plot(lm2)
```

I don't see anything too troublesome in these plots.

Comment: Thanks @Alex not seen the line up plots before - always useful to have more options